# How to create a socket connection using Oracle SOA suite?

Tags: soa, oracle-soa

I am completely new to Oracle SOA suite and dont know where to start...
I want to create a socket connection using SOA suite and maintain it's connection 
with a system for asynchronous communication
or in other words I want to create a socket adapter for Asynchronous communication
Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

In reading your question, I can only assume you're not planning on performing some form of web service call using HTTP/SOAP.  Socket communication is pretty low-level for the kind of tooling SOA Suite supports out-of-the-box, but there is support for JCA adapter connections to BPEL processes in the tool.

Check out the documentation on [Oracle JCA Adapter for Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/integration.1111/e10231/adptr_sock.htm#BABEBEJH) first, then see if what you're trying to accomplish will fit with that or not.

If not, you might be better served writing a Java client EJB module or even just a simple .jar and integrate it into your BPEL with it.  The documentation for that would be under [Integrating Enterprise JavaBeans with SOA Composite Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/dev.1111/e10224/sca_sdo_ejb.htm#BAJBCFGE)

Also, the documentation for SOA Suite is a great place to dig around to see what is natively supported as well as what can be extended:

- [ORACLE SOA SUITE, BUSINESS PROCESS MANAGEMENT SUITE, AND WEB SERVICES DOCUMENTATION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/soa.htm)
- [Oracle SOA Suite Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/documentation/index.html#111170)

My apologies if this isn't specific enough for you.  I'd like to know more about what you're trying to communicate with, but I imagine that if it's some specialized application or device that doesn't support SOAP/WSDL over HTTP, these probably the best places to start.

Comment: Let say there is a system;   
so I want to create a socket connection to the system at the time when it boots and remains connected to it asynchronously whether there is a request/ response session going on or not and remain connected to it.
The requirement is accomplishing it using oracle SOA suite.
I am checking out the documentation on socket adapter.....
let's see..